# Facebook API, how to get relationship status of friends(single, married, etc...)?

Tags: facebook

could somebody help me with Facebook API, how to get relationship status of friends(single, married, etc...)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to get an access token with [user_relationships](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/#extended_perms), call https://graph.facebook.com/YOURFRIEND-ID and check "relationship_status" in the returned JSON string. 
Just have in mind that if your friend didn't filled his relationship data into his profile, there will be no "relationship_status" at the returned user info.

Comment: can you give me link or more details ? , Thanks

Comment: Can anyone help on this issue..!

Answer (score 2):

Try this FQL in the [Graph explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

`fql?q=SELECT uid, name, relationship_status FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())`

Answer (score 1):

You will no longer be allowed to get friends information in v2.0.

Comment: Has this been verified?  

From https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-pull-a-friends-Relationship-Status-history-from-Facebook-API

Get an access token with access to friends' relationship status changes

FQL Query:
SELECT type,description,created_time from stream where source_id = ID_OF_SOMEONE and (strpos(lower(description),'married') >= 0 OR strpos(lower(description),'went from') >= 0 OR strpos(lower(description),'is single') >= 0 OR strpos(lower(description),'relationship') >= 0) LIMIT 1000

^ searches for posts that include 'relationship', 'married', 'went from' & 'single'.