# Return Facebook user info in local language

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a small app with Xcode that logs into Facebook and retrieves user informations. This is the part of code that performs the request:

```
 [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
   NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
   NSError *error) {
   if (!error) {
     // at this point user variable contains all user's info I need
     NSLog (@"%@", user.name); 
   } else {
     NSLog(@"ERRORE");
   }
 }];
```

These infos are returned in English. How can I retrieve them in the same language of Facebook  profile ? For example, since the language I choose for my Facebook profile is Italian, I need to retrieve all my infos in italian (with this code user[@"relationship_status"] returns "married", it should return "sposato")

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140523/facebook-api-how-to-get-relationship-status-of-friendssingle-married-etc) I found out (a possible) solution: run a FQL query with the **locale** parameter set to the desired language. In my case it should be **locale=it_IT**, as stated by [this table](http://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml)