# Login to facebook api and scheduled events

Tags: ios, .net, facebook, asp.net-web-api

I have a setup where users are required to log into my ios application using facebook. I want to poll their friend's information every couple hours and notify them on any changes.  Is this possible with what is allowed by facebook api? Essentially, if i user facebook ios login to sign the user in, and I receive an access token, could I use that token days or weeks later?

Comment: You can't access friends information. So no it is not possible

Comment: Here is an example of how it is possible to get friend information.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140523/facebook-api-how-to-get-relationship-status-of-friendssingle-married-etc

Comment: that thread is from 2012, a lot of things changed since then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As WizKid commented, you can´t access friends information anymore, friend permissions are deprecated since v2.0, as you can read in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Information about Access Tokens and how long they are valid can be found here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Also, polling information is a very bad idea, if you want to check for changes (of an authorized user only!), you better user the Realtime API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/

Comment: How can tinder determine shared interest or mutual friends if it cannot view details about the individual friend

Comment: they are using a v1.0 app - old apps can still use v1.0 until april 2015. a lot of apps will stop working after that.

Comment: In other words, I can get friends information until april 2015 using v 1.0

Comment: not exactly. you could only get friends information (and use v1.0 in general) with an app created before end of april 2014. you can´t use an app created after april 2014.